# aes-256-gcm decryption in php

Tags: php

I am trying to decrypt a JSON payload using aes-256-gcm algorithm. Well at first it was not  working in php5.6 and got worked in <php7.1

The issue is if we try to decrypt the encrypted JSON data, it is only decrypting if the encryption and decryption is defined in the same function but I have to encrypt data in one function after calling the encryption function in decryption function it is throwing a blank response.

```
public function encrypt() {
    $key = 'f901cfe8a69615a93fdf7a98cad48179';
    $method = 'aes-256-gcm';
    $data = JSON_encode(array("payload"=>'Hello there this is plain JSON data'));
    $iv = 12 bit(initialization vector);
    
   return trim(opensssl_encrypt($data, $method, $key, $options=0, $iv));
        }
        
public function decrypt() {
    $encrypted = $this->encrypt();
    $key = 'f901cfe8a69615a93fdf7a98cad48179';
    $method = 'aes-256-gcm';
    $iv = chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0);
    $response = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, $method, $key, $options=0,$iv);        
    return  
    }
```

for the decrypt function if we do this..

```
public function decrypt() {
    $key = 'f901cfe8a69615a93fdf7a98cad48179';
    $method = 'aes-256-cbc';
    $iv = chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) .   chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0);
    $encrypted2 = openssl_encrypt(arguments(same as in the encrypt function));
    $response=openssl_decrypt($encrypted2, $method, $key, $options=0,$iv);         
    return  
    }
```

This is working.
Can anyone please help. I tried to search for this I found a comment in which it stated we have to encrypt data just before the decryption. But it would not work for me. Lets say you will get the data from a client in aes-256-gcm enc algorithm. I would like to decrypt that.
Thanks..!

Comment: You ignore that you used `trim()` in one case but not in the other. Also your IV can be set much more conveniently thru `"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"` (which are 12 **bytes**, not bits).

Comment: Okay I will try for iv but this is not working if I use trim or not. Thanks

Comment: Your second decrypt function uses a different AES mode - it uses **CBC** instead of requested **GCM** mode. Secondly: using static = fixed IV's makes your encryption totally **UNSECURE** - never ever do this in production. Create a randomly generated IV and transport it along with the encrypted material.

Comment: In the code with GCM mode, the authentication tag is not taken into account, which is why decryption fails. The tag is returned by reference in the 6th parameter during encryption and _must_ be passed in the 6th parameter during decryption. If the tag is missing or incorrect, authentication and thus decryption will fail. Also, of course, the IV/nonce must be identical for encryption and decryption.